# How to detect exit code from SSIS package after running from command line?

Tags: command-line, ssis

I have an SSIS package which I have been running from the command line. Once the package is run from the command line, I'd like to check the exit code. And If the exit code results in an error. Then I would like to log to a text file. I can log to a text file, I just can't detect the error. Can anyone help?

So far I have this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn>dtexec.exe /f "T:\Development\.NET Projects\ReportingTool\DailyUpload_DEV\DailyUpload\DailyUpload_Morr.dtsx" <This is where I need the IF to check the return code> ECHO HELLO>>\\tw2-dc02\users$\Akilburn\Documents\text.txt
```

And the package returns this on failure:

```
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking the wrong variable. The IF is supposed to look like this `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO HELLO>>\\tw2-dc02\users$\Akilburn_MORR\Documents\text.txt`